# Capture video in the background with Flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter, camera, android-camera2

I'm using [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera), but it isn't possible to capture video with locked screen. Maybe someone know, how to implement this?

Comment: @user1241241 You can try this example https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/camera/example/lib/main.dart